# canvas animate the bar till the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I usually do not work with canvas consequently know very little about it. Some help would be very appreciated.
So I have found this somewhere in the internet.

```js
window.Hayk = {}
Hayk.percent = 85
$(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas = $("#c"),
  c = canvas[0].getContext("2d"),
  cDim = {
   w: 400,
   h: 400
  },
  gui = new dat.GUI();

 c.canvas.width = cDim.w;
 c.canvas.height = cDim.h;

 var params = new function() {
  this.line_width = 15;
  
  this.start_ang = Math.PI * 0.75;
  this.end_ang = Math.PI * 0.25;
  
  this.range_max = 0.785;
  this.range_min = -3.92;
  
  this.current_percent = Hayk.percent;
  
  this.step_1 = () => {
   return (this.range_max - this.range_min)/100;
  }
 }

 draw_progress(params.current_percent);

 gui.add(params, "current_percent", 0, 100).listen().onChange(function(e) {
   c.clearRect(0, 0, cDim.w, cDim.h);
   draw_progress(e);
 });

 function draw_progress(percent) {
  draw_path();
  
  var current_ang = params.range_min + (percent * params.step_1());
  
  $(".count").html(Math.round(percent) + "/100");

  c.beginPath();

  c.arc(cDim.w * 0.5, cDim.h * 0.55, cDim.w * 0.45, params.start_ang, current_ang);

  c.lineWidth = params.line_width;
  c.strokeStyle = "red";
        if (percent>20 && percent<=50) c.strokeStyle = "orange"
        if (percent>50 && percent<=80) c.strokeStyle = "yellow"
        if (percent>80) c.strokeStyle = "#35c805"
  c.lineCap = "round";
  c.stroke();
 }

 function draw_path() {
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(cDim.w * 0.5, cDim.h * 0.55, cDim.w * 0.45, params.start_ang, params.end_ang);
  c.lineWidth = params.line_width + 5;
  c.strokeStyle = "#999";
  c.lineCap = "round";
  c.stroke();
 }
 
 function adjust_window() {
  if(window.width < 400) {
   c.canvas.width = window.width; c.Dim.w = window.width;
   c.canvas.height = window.width; c.Dim.h = window.width;
  }
 }
 $(".dg.main").css("display","none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/519606/dat-0.5.1.gui.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

I wonder if there's a way to fill the bar with animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some changes in the draw_progress function:

```
function draw_progress(percent) {
    var currentPercent = 0; // track the percent that's actually shown
    $(".count").html(Math.round(percent) + "/100");

    var drawing = setInterval(function(){ // draw every 10 ms
      if(currentPercent >= percent){ // if you reach the final percent stop
        clearInterval(drawing);
        return;
      }else // else clear the canvas
        c.clearRect(0, 0, cDim.w, cDim.h);
      currentPercent++; //this value change the animation speed (+0.5 slower, +1.5 faster)
      // draw everything like before except use currentPercent instead of percent
      draw_path();
      var current_ang = params.range_min + (currentPercent * params.step_1());
      c.beginPath();

      c.arc(cDim.w * 0.5, cDim.h * 0.55, cDim.w * 0.45, params.start_ang, current_ang);

      c.lineWidth = params.line_width;
      c.strokeStyle = "red";
      if (currentPercent>20 && currentPercent<=50) c.strokeStyle = "orange"
      if (currentPercent>50 && currentPercent<=80) c.strokeStyle = "yellow"
      if (currentPercent>80) c.strokeStyle = "#35c805"
      c.lineCap = "round";
      c.stroke();
    }, 10)

}
```

```js
window.Hayk = {}
Hayk.percent = 85
$(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas = $("#c"),
  c = canvas[0].getContext("2d"),
  cDim = {
   w: 400,
   h: 400
  },
  gui = new dat.GUI();

 c.canvas.width = cDim.w;
 c.canvas.height = cDim.h;

 var params = new function() {
  this.line_width = 15;
  
  this.start_ang = Math.PI * 0.75;
  this.end_ang = Math.PI * 0.25;
  
  this.range_max = 0.785;
  this.range_min = -3.92;
  
  this.current_percent = Hayk.percent;
  
  this.step_1 = () => {
   return (this.range_max - this.range_min)/100;
  }
 }

 draw_progress(params.current_percent);

 gui.add(params, "current_percent", 0, 100).listen().onChange(function(e) {
   c.clearRect(0, 0, cDim.w, cDim.h);
   draw_progress(e);
 });

 function draw_progress(percent) {
  var currentPercent = 0;
  $(".count").html(Math.round(percent) + "/100");
         
        var drawing = setInterval(function(){
          if(currentPercent >= percent){
            clearInterval(drawing);
            return;
          }else
            c.clearRect(0, 0, cDim.w, cDim.h);
          currentPercent+=0.5;
          draw_path();
          var current_ang = params.range_min + (currentPercent * params.step_1());
    c.beginPath();

    c.arc(cDim.w * 0.5, cDim.h * 0.55, cDim.w * 0.45, params.start_ang, current_ang);
  
    c.lineWidth = params.line_width;
    c.strokeStyle = "red";
          if (currentPercent>20 && currentPercent<=50) c.strokeStyle = "orange"
          if (currentPercent>50 && currentPercent<=80) c.strokeStyle = "yellow"
          if (currentPercent>80) c.strokeStyle = "#35c805"
    c.lineCap = "round";
    c.stroke();
        }, 10)
        
 }

 function draw_path() {
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(cDim.w * 0.5, cDim.h * 0.55, cDim.w * 0.45, params.start_ang, params.end_ang);
  c.lineWidth = params.line_width + 5;
  c.strokeStyle = "#999";
  c.lineCap = "round";
  c.stroke();
 }
 
 function adjust_window() {
  if(window.width < 400) {
   c.canvas.width = window.width; c.Dim.w = window.width;
   c.canvas.height = window.width; c.Dim.h = window.width;
  }
 }
 $(".dg.main").css("display","none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/519606/dat-0.5.1.gui.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```